# Bootstrap Multiselect Get Selected values on HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using this [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started) and my problem is that I cant get the selected values on HttpPost on ASP.Net MVC.

Problems Encountered:

- after clicking save, Only the first selected value is the present on
  the model. (**SOLVED**)
- after clicking save, Only the first selected value is the present on
  the dropdownlist.

Sample.chtml:

```
@model SampleProject.Models.SampleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selected, new SelectList(Model.List, "value", "text"), new { @class = "multiselect form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Model:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public string[] Selected { get; set; }
    public SelectList List { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Sample()
    {
        SampleViewModel model = new SampleViewModel();
        model.List = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Sample(SampleViewModel model)
    {
        model.List = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Selection:

[image: Selection]

**I cant get the selected values correctly on HttpPost**

Code Behind/HttpPost: (Wrong)
[image: HttpPost]

After HttpPost: (Correct)

[image: After]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `<select multiple="multiple">` posts back an array of values (not a single value). You property `Selected` needs to be `IEnumerable`, for example

```
public string[] Selected { get; set; }
```

Side note: Since the text and value properties are the same, you can simplify you code by making the `List` property `SelectList`

```
public SelectList List { get; set; }
```

and then in the controller

```
model.List = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" })
```

(although its not clear why you would not use `int`)

Comment: Sir, I have another problem after clicking save.

Comment: after clicking **Save**, Instead of Multiple items, only the first selected value if shown as selected on the **DropdownList**.(refer to the 3rd picture above.)

Comment: You have not reassigned the the `SelectList` when you return the view.

Comment: Sir, I've done that but still it returns only one selected item. (Refer to the code above.)

Comment: What is `string[] Selecteds = model.Selected;` for? (where do you use the value `Selecteds`). Have you changed the property `Selected` to typeof `string[]`? Also you should remove the bootstrap plugin and test it using the default html select element

Comment: Hi sir, I already updated the code above and I've also tried removing the bootstrap plugin and the result was still the same.

Comment: The code works fine (I have already tested what you have shown here). You must have other issues that you have not shown.

Comment: Sir, I've updated the code based on your given solution and the problem goes back to getting the selected values on HttpPost. And the same output even without bootstrap plugin.

Comment: You have completely changed your question with all this new code (instead of appending the revised code) making my answer pointless. But if you use `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Selected, Model.List)` it all works fine.

Comment: Sorry sir, didn't mean to change the code. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Didn't see this answer anywhere, so to solve the issue with having only 1 item selected after the post back you need to use:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(.. 
instead of @Html.DropDownListFor
```