# how to get bootstrap multiselect selected values from code behind?

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

It is very easy to get `bootstrap multiselect listbox's` selected values using `javascript` like this

```
$('listbox1').val();
```

But I want to access it from code behind.

Comment: Could you post some more information about the rest of your solution? Are you using asp.net? php? etc

Comment: I am using asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get more/better assistance by posting some of your code or what you have tried.

However, this might put you in the right direction?:
[Bootstrap Multiselect Get Selected values on HttpPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466959/bootstrap-multiselect-get-selected-values-on-httppost)