# how to change single selection to multiselect dropdown with checkboxes using asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using below code for dropdown

```
@if (ViewBag.EventContentTypeId == Convert.ToInt32(EventContentType.Events))
{
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group input" style="padding-left:0">
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.DropDownList("EventCategoryDDL", @ViewBag.EventCategories as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select Category --", new { @class = "form-control" })
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I want to change these to multi-select dropdown with checkbox.

And this is my controller code and this is in selectlist and I am unable to modify to multiselectlist is there a way to change to multiselectlist of selectlist.

```
ViewBag.EventCategories = ViewBag.EventContentTypeName == EventContentTypeString.Events.Value ? _commonService.GetEventCategoriesModel().Where(category =>category.OptionText != "Camp Kaufmann").Select(i => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = i.OptionText,
    Value = i.OptionValue.ToString()
})
_commonService.GetEventCategoriesModel().Select(i => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = i.OptionText,
    Value = i.OptionValue.ToString()
});
```

And how should I change to multiselectlist in my controller side and also how to bind dropdown with check boxes of multiselect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC multiple select dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013223/asp-net-mvc-multiple-select-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bootstrap-multiselect` plugin check [this](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) link.

**Action Methods**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

  List <SelectListItem> vegList = new List<SelectListItem>
  {
  new SelectListItem {Text = "Cheese",Value="1" },
  new SelectListItem {Text = "Mushrooms",Value="2" },
  new SelectListItem {Text = "Tomatoes",Value="3" },
  new SelectListItem {Text = "Onions",Value="4" }
  };

  ViewBag.Vegetables = vegList;

    return View();
}




[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddVegetables(string[] VegetablesDDL)
{
  var selectedVegetablesIDs = VegetablesDDL.ToList();

  foreach(var selected in selectedVegetablesIDs)
  {
    // use selected item
  }

      return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddVegetables", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Label("Vegetables:")
    <br />
    <br />
  @Html.DropDownList("VegetablesDDL", @ViewBag.Vegetables as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select Vegetables 
  --", new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#VegetablesDDL').multiselect();
});
</script>
```

Note:

Add `bootstrap-multiselect.css` in head section of your page and `bootstrap-multiselect.js` in bottom of your page.

Also its better to use `ViewModels` instead of `ViewBag` check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466959/bootstrap-multiselect-get-selected-values-on-httppost).

Reference:

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466959/bootstrap-multiselect-get-selected-values-on-httppost)

[2.](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bootstrap-Multiple-Select-Multi-Select-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-MVC-Razor.aspx)